# orderBy filter not sorting dynamically added ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

When I add content dynamically to an array, ng-repeat won't respect the orderBy filter.

Please have a look at the example I have created:
http://jsfiddle.net/fPX7R/2/

```
<script>
    function RedditAuthor (name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
    var redditPostUrl = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/26lfww/python_why_does_10_2_100_and_not_100.json';
    var huebelApp = angular.module('huebelApp', []);
    huebelApp.controller('LightCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.authors = [];
        $http.get(redditPostUrl).success(function(postData) {
            for (var i=0; i<postData[1].data.children.length; ++i) {
                var commentId = postData[1].data.children[i].data.id;
                $http.get(redditPostUrl+'/'+commentId+'.json').success(function(commentData){
                    var authorName = commentData[1].data.children[0].data.author;
                    $scope.authors.push(new RedditAuthor(''+authorName));
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="huebelApp" ng-controller="LightCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="author in authors | orderBy:name">
        <span>{{author.name}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

In this example I query a reddit post and issue a query for each top level comment. The result of the comment query is then added to the array which ng-repeat displays. However the order is not maintained.

How can I tell angular to respect the filter and sort the list, when the content is added dynamically?

Comment: Did you try `orderBy:'name'`? note `name` is in single-quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orderBy is missing quotes around it...

```
<body ng-app="huebelApp" ng-controller="LightCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="author in authors | orderBy:'name'">
        <span>{{author.name}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPX7R/4/)